# How to select music folder on iOS in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, folderbrowserdialog, apple-music

I'm developing a flutter app and I need to reproduce some music from the device allowing the user to choose the folder where the music files are stored.

I tried to use the package file_picker (https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) that should open the dialog to navigate the file system and allows the user to select a folder but I could not find a way to select the music folder.

I put some music in the iphone and if I use the Music app I could play them but I could don't see them or the music folder at all from my app.

How could I navigate the file system on iOS to select a music folder and retrieve its path?